# Is this the correct format for a cron job?

Tags: linux, command-line, cron

I am trying to delete files in the `1` folder if they are older than 1 day. What I need to know is if the following cron job will do this.

```
find /public_html/kronofiles.com/uploads/1/ -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: `find /public_html/kronofiles.com/uploads/1/ -mtime -1 -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: what is the difference? `-1`? I don't have any experience with linux/ cronjobs

Comment: This will try to delete files *and folders* older than 1 day from that folder. It might generate warnings if asked to delete folders, since `rm` only works on files. Add `-type f` in there to choose just files.

Comment: how would i delete folders too?

Comment: After the `find` command that you already have, run `find /public_html/kronofiles.com/uploads/1/* -type d -mtime +1 -exec rmdir {} \;` . This will try to remove all folders that haven't been modified in the past day.  The '*' is so that it only looks at subdirectories of `/public_html/kronofiles.com/uploads/1`, since you probably don't want to delete that folder itself. `rmdir` will only remove empty folders; you still need the `find ... -exec rm ...` command to remove files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an example line from a crontab file

```
0 0 * * 0 sh /path/to/file
```

this says execute the file at 00:00 everyday. next comes the command to execute. `sh` in this case for a shell script. this could be many things, PHP for example. next is the file you want to execute.

are you asking how to format a crontab entry? or are you asking if your script will work when executed?

Comment: i would retag this with something more appropriate then, since you really don't need help with the cron portion of it, but rather the scripting. might help you get better answers.

Comment: would this run though? i'm doing this through my host cpanel

Comment: if you have SSH access you can execute `crontab -e` and directly edit your cron file with a line similar to mine above. if you're going through cpanel, you'll likely have some kind of simplied UI to select your timing, and then input your command. i'm not as versed in command line as others, so hopefully someone else can help with the content of the command. if you have SSH access, go ahead and test out the command first, and it'll give you any error messages.